# How to find 2 items in a list that are the same in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list populated with ~100 names. The names in this list either occur once or twice and I would like to go through the list to find names that occur *twice* and names that only occur *once*. I will also need the position of the reoccurring names in the list and the positions of the names that only appear once.

I'm not sure how I would go about doing this because all the methods I can think of are inefficient as they would go through the whole list even if they have already found a match. Other methods that I can think of would return two duplicate positions. The names that occur twice will not necessarily be adjacent to each other.

For example, if this was the list:

```
mylist = [ 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 5, 6]
```

I would need something that outputs (something like):

```
[[0,3],[1],[2],[4,5],[6],[7]]
```

With those numbers being the positions of the duplicate names and the position of the names that occur once.

I am by no means an expert so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `from collections import defaultdict; new = defaultdict()` then `for i, j in enumerate(myList): q[j].append(i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a dictionary:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,1,4,4,5,6]
dic = {}

for i in range(0,len(mylist)):
    if mylist[i] in dic:
        dic[mylist[i]].append(i)
    else:
        dic[mylist[i]] = [i]
print dic.values()
# prints [[0, 3], [1], [2], [4, 5], [6], [7]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `enumerate` to get the pairs contain index of each element and the element itself then loop over it and store the items as key and indices as values using a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) (to preserve the order) and [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d=OrderedDict()
>>> for i,j in enumerate(mylist):
...     d.setdefault(j,[]).append(i)
... 

>>> d.values()
[[0, 3], [1], [2], [4, 5], [6], [7]]
```